# Is there a bug with notifications and migrated questions?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, answers, edits, migrated-questions

I answered [Is software development an engineering discipline?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111265/software-development-and-engineering) when it was on Stack Overflow in 2008. Last night, I edited my answer to that question on Programmers. When I visited Stack Overflow this morning, I had a notification that my answer to the question was migrated. This might have to do with the age of the question and how notifications have changed (for example, I think there was a time when you weren't notified if you answered a question that was migrated), but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were notified because although the question is older it was indeed [*just migrated*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/209551/revisions) yesterday, and that's all that matters for the notification times, regardless of when it was created.  The time you edited doesn't factor in, you would have been notified of the migration anyway.

Comment: Interesting. I missed that giant bold "yesterday", especially since there were similar questions on Programmers in the past, I just figured this was one of the older ones and not a newly migrated one.